# How to add a custom SSL verification to MySql Connector/NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

As you know, there is a

```
System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
```

in .NET that allows you to decide whether to trust the certificate sent by the server. You can use this in SslStream and ServicePointManager.

Now im trying to use the same pattern during MySql Connector/NET. In MySql server-side, i set a self-signed certificate. When i use the option `SslMode=VerifyCA` in client(based on MySql Connector/NET), the connecting failed because my CA is not trusted in client side.

I know i can just simply add the CA certificate to client's system trustzone, but this solution is not portable.

So the problem is: Is there any MySql Connector/NET API that allows user to provide a
    `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` or something like that?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bradley-grainger says, in the 3rd-party MySqlConnector library, there is an Connection String argument called "CACertificateFile", which allows you trust an CA certificate which is not located in system trust zone.

Unfortunately, this option is not available in the official Connector/NET. And for some reasons, i can't switch to the MySqlConnector library.

So i just forked the official Connector/NET repository in github, and added "CACertificateFile" feature to it, it perfectly solved my problem.

If you meet the same situation, i believe it will be helpful.

see https://github.com/liuziangexit/mysql-connector-net/commit/d22652036ece49f8d2f48d10b0bdc57f92e22c26, based on official 6.10.8 source.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any MySql Connector/NET API that allows user to provide a RemoteCertificateValidationCallback or something like that?

No, there is not. Either the certificate must be acceptable to the machine, or you use an unencrypted connection.

> I know i can just simply add the CA certificate to client's system trustzone, but this solution is not portable.

If you need this to be portable, you'll need to get a certificate from a trusted certificate authority like Symantec, DigiCert, GeoTrust, etc. Otherwise, you'll just have to bite the bullet on adding your self-signed cert to the certificate store on each computer that connects to the DB.

Comment: Thats the truth! i just browsed the source code of MySql Connector, and there is a fixed internal RemoteCertificateValidationCallback which is invisible to API user, so you are correct !

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the [MySqlConnector library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), which adds a `CACertificateFile` option to the [connection string](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/) (more info [here](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/278)).

When you use this setting and specify a PEM file for the CA Certificate, this will make `SslMode=VerifyCA` in your connection string have the desired effect of validating your custom SSL certificate.

Comment: Yes i notice that MySqlConnector library is exactly what i want, but the problem is my project is not based on pure Connector code, im using the linq2db library. If i switch to MySqlConnector, i need to write a new linq2db DataProvider based on MySqlConnector...anyway, thanks for your help!